# some number theory method can be used to solve this example quickly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science, hash-function

I have extract some notes from my notes:

[image: Images from Notes]

one way to found which of four example is uniform function is that try by hand and take some examples. I will search for a method that we can easily infer just the second one has uniform capability. is there any hint or idea to quickly choose the second one instead of try by hand and examples one by one?

for the last one:
$h(1)=1, (h3)=4, h(2)=4$ so means not uniform because $x=3$ and $x=2$ has the same slot.

Comment: the letter $k$ appears only at the example part, does $k$ and $m$  mean the same thing? can you include example of how you verify to show that you have made an effort for this question? are the domain defined explicitly for you?

Comment: try to show more attempts so that the rest can help you. on this site, the more effort you show, you more likely you will get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to distribute stuff to $k$ slots. Computing over modulo $k-1$ would not make you attain $k$ slots, hence immediately, we reject the first and third choice.

You can then try some simple number, say when $k=4$ to reject the last case.

Note that $k-1$ and $k$ are coprime. if $a$ and $k$ are coprime, we know that $ax \pmod{k}$ would achieve a bijection.

Comment: if $a$ and $k$ are coprime, then $a^{-1}\pmod{k}$ exists, try to use that to prove $f(x) = ax \pmod{k}$ is a bijection.

Comment: yes, try to prove it :)